# WP All Import Plugin Import XML - Error

Tags: php, wordpress

When trying to import a csv file using the WP All Import Plugin everything is fine until I get to the final "Finish" step that does the import.  At that point the import fails and gives me a generic "Import XML - Error" display Created 0/Updated 0 of 29 records.

This was working previously, now it is failing on all files, even ones that I know were working previously.

Is there some type of debug logging for this?  I don't see anything on the plugin documentation that show's where I can even look to start debugging.  Sorry, but I'm Wordpress noob.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by lowering the number of records processed in each iteration.
Here's a link that might be helpful: http://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/step-4/import-processing/

Cheers,
Sergiu